# Suppose that complexes $K_1$ and $K_2$ have the same simplexes but different orientations. How are the chain groups $C_p(K_1)$ and $C_P(K_2)$ related?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose that complexes $K_1$ and $K_2$ have the same simplexes but different
orientations. How are the chain groups $C_p(K_1)$ and $C_P(K_2)$ related?

I think nothing changed and they are isomorphic,because the generators won't change.

again please make me right if I am mistaking.thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried doing this with a small example to compare the complexes?

Comment: I was imaging a 2-simplex (triangle) that have two different orientation,and I consider vertices and edges as generators in both cases and I think just the boundary  operation will change.